# conditional method for sorting array into description of array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, model

How can I make the current view found below look like the view with your help?

current view:

```
<%= challenge.action %>
<% @challenge.committed.map { |d| d.titleize[0,3] }.each do |title| %>
  <%= title %> 
<% end %>

# EXAMPLES
# Run    Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat
# Meditate    Sun, Sat
# Do a Random Act of Kindness    Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri
```

view with your help:

```
<%= @challenge.action %> <%= @challenge.committed_description %> # Trying to make committed_description work

# EXAMPLES
# Run everyday
# Meditate weekends
# Do a Random Act of Kindness weekdays
```

overall idea for model method (pseudo-code):

```
def committed_description
  if ["sun", "mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri", "sat"]
   "everyday"
  elsif ["mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri"]
    "weekdays"
  elsif ["sun", "sat"]
    "weekends" 
end
```

challenge.rb:

```
class Challenge < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :committed, Array

  def committed_wdays
    committed.map do |day|    
      Date::ABBR_DAYNAMES.index(day.titleize)
    end
  end
end
```

db:

```
t.text     "committed",       default: "---\n- sun\n- mon\n- tue\n- wed\n- thu\n- fri\n- sat\n"
```

Comment: Are you trying to tackle the `committed_description` part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to figure out what a good label for this is, write a method specifically for that:

```
WEEKDAYS = %w[ mon tue wed thu fri ]
WEEKENDS = %w[ sat sun ]
DAYS = WEEKDAYS + WEEKENDS

def committed_description
  case DAYS & self.committed
  when DAYS
    'everyday'
  when WEEKDAYS
    'weekdays'
  when WEEKENDS
    'weekends'
  else
    self.commited.join(', ')
  end
end
```

Ruby can straight up compare array vs. array to see if they're equal and branch into the appropriate section. This is quite handy.

It's worth noting that using an array for this is extremely heavy handed. You might want to use a shorter notation, assigning a unique letter for each day and treating that as a description. For example: `MTWHFSU` is a common mapping, `H` for Thursday and `U` for Sunday being the anomalies.

Serialized columns are brutally slow to work with compared to their simple string counterparts. Instead of serializing/unserializing on each read, you just fetch a string, and instead of comparing array vs. array you compare string vs. string. It's way more efficient. As a bonus these strings can be neatly indexed.

Comment: It's not just speed, but simplicity. Having a compact, canonical way of storing data like this helps with development and debugging. I've fixed up the example here due to `sort` issues. Forcing `DAYS &` will put them in the correct order every time and has the additional benefit of discarding any non-day data.

Comment: Thank you sir! I will make the adjust at some point. I feel like for every problem I solve three more pop up lol. I guess that's the life of a programmer.